# Why I always fail on loading big files in lua?

Tags: lua

This is my code. The file has like 1 million lines and 134mb. I don't think it is a big file but why I always failed loading it? It shows "out of memory" when reading at like 700,000 lines. Is there any lua mechanism I don't know? I use luajit.

```
function unsupervised_re.read_seq_ids(seq_path)
    local seq_ids = {}
    local file = io.open(seq_path, 'r')
    local count = 0
    while true do
        local line = file:read()
        count = count + 1
        print (count)
        if line == nil then break end
        local tokens = stringx.split(line, ' ')
        seq_ids[#seq_ids+1] = tokens
    end
    file:close()
    return seq_ids
end
```

Comment: Why do you need to copy `tokens` to `ids`?

Comment: Just for organizing the data conveniently.

Comment: How? You're just making an exact copy.

Comment: Yeah, I see. Maybe that's a flaw. But I don't think it will cause the "out of memory".  Because when I put the task on the cluster, I assigned the cluster 128g RAM. There was still the error. I think 128G is enough for even 100 times bigger file size.

Comment: I modified the code and it stopped at 900,000 lines. Still the "out of memory".

Comment: There's hard limit of 2Gb that can be used by LuaJIT thanks to some GC quirks. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015150/how-to-get-past-1gb-memory-limit-of-64-bit-luajit-on-linux. You need to either reduce overhead (just like that minimal change did, but there's not much else you can do), use better data structures or manage memory manually with FFI.

Comment: Thanks.. It seems to be the problem. I just searched. Somebody told me maybe I could switch to lua 52. I will have a try.